# Zenoss Graph results of postgresql database query

Tags: zenoss

So I just added my servers to Zenoss and installed some postgresql zenpacks. Unfortunatly I do not care for most of the postgresql monitoring tools. Instead of what they gave me, I am wondering if it is possible to send a custom query that I wrote, then graph the result using Zenoss? How do I go about doing this? Are there any good resources that you know of?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write your own ZenPack (or at least Template). Check Development Guide http://wiki.zenoss.org/ZenPack_Development_Guide or http://zenosslabs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/zenpack_development/

IMHO you will need zencommand datasource, which will execute your custom SQL query and this query output (number only) will be metric value, which will be processed by Zenoss.

Or you can expose metric(s) via SNMP and then it'll be only standard SNMP metric in Zenoss.

It's up to you how do you implement it. I recommend you to use community forum http://www.zenoss.org/forum for Zenoss related questions.